# Migrate [Microsoft-Surface] tag to [PixelSense]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

With Microsoft rebranding the Surface touchscreen to PixelSense, SO should do the same and migrate existing questions tagged [microsoft-surface](/questions/tagged/microsoft-surface) to [pixelsense](/questions/tagged/pixelsense) and make [microsoft-surface](/questions/tagged/microsoft-surface) refer exclusively to the handheld tablet.

As for [surface](/questions/tagged/surface) questions, ones about the Microsoft touchscreen should also be retagged [microsoft-surface](/questions/tagged/microsoft-surface).

Comment: Yes, the rebranding is retroactive; the old platform is no longer called "Surface", it is called PixelSense; look at http://www.surface.com/; it's exclusively about the new tablet. All the old content has been migrated to http://www.pixelSense.com/

Comment: **What about [Surface] - the math term?** That alone is easily a big reason to keep it. (Or to change your suggestion to. Please, retag all ms-surface questions. Probably not a good use of moderation-time).

Comment: @Olof, I could not find a single use of the [Surface] tag in SO referring to the math term, every existing usage is to what is now called PixelSense. Questions tagged [Microsoft-Surface] should also be changed to [PixelSense].

Comment: No offence but. You can't have been looking. I could go on an on. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338385 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716837 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488086 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120066

Comment: @Olof, finding other questions also not about PixelSense hardly makes existing wrongly-tagged ones correct. I am not suggesting that questions about mathematical surfaces be retagged, only wrongly-tagged ones.

Comment: @Dour: I think what Olof is getting at is that we can't just *rename* the surface tag unless the *only* questions in it refer to what is now "pixelsense".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As has been mentioned in the comments, [surface](/questions/tagged/surface) isn't unique to questions on what are now called "PixelSense". So straight-up renaming this is out of the question.

[microsoft-surface](/questions/tagged/microsoft-surface) could be renamed. Given the rebranding, it's probably worth doing so early, before questions on the *new* surface start showing up. So I've done so - **but I've left the previous tag as a synonym of the new for the time being**. We may want to remove this after news of the name change has been disseminated a bit.

You can start re-tagging applicable [surface](/questions/tagged/surface) questions to [pixelsense](/questions/tagged/pixelsense) at your leisure.