# Obsolete synonym: [Microsoft-Surface] and  [PixelSense] are now separate products

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms

I found that the tag [pixelsense](/questions/tagged/pixelsense) has [microsoft-surface](/questions/tagged/microsoft-surface) as a synonym. I know that PixelSense was previously named Microsoft Surface.

However, as you probably heard, Microsoft is now releasing a tablet called Microsoft Surface, which is unrelated to PixelSense. Because of this, Microsoft Surface and PixelSense shouldn't be synonyms anymore.

Comment: We know about it. Take a look at this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136946/migrate-microsoft-surface-tag-to-pixelsense

Comment: You're right, but if that question has status completed, why are these two tags still synonyms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created the synonym because PixelSense had *just* been announced, as had the Surface tablet. So expecting folks to use the right tags for either one would've been kinda silly.

When folks start actually asking questions about [the Surface *tablet*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/surface-tablet), we can break the synonym; until then, it's probably less confusing to leave it be.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand.