# Changing Tag Wiki for the tfs-service tag

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag wiki for [tfs-service](/questions/tagged/tfs-service) currently says:

> tfs Stands for Team Foundation Server , where tfs services refer to a server for Team Foundation, where you can view the services that Visual Studio Team Foundation Server uses and the Web Service application pools that Team Foundation Server installs. Team Foundation Server includes many services that run on the application tier.

Both of the questions which currently have this tag are instead about the new Team Foundation Service (http://tfs.visualstudio.com/).

I see no value in this tag if it is truly intended to have the meaning currently described in the wiki. I would prefer it to refer to the new hosted service.

Any suggestions?

Comment: That tag wiki makes me oh so confused.

Comment: I recently cleaned up [tag:team-foundation-service] and threw together a rough wiki for it.  I don't think [tag:tfs-service] is an appropriate tag, as it doesn't actually stand for what it represents (team foundation server service?  Have some pizza pie while you're at it).  The [tag:tfs] tag kind of sucks, on a side note.  Not sure what the best solution to all this is :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that tag sucks. But so does the product naming, since [tfs](/questions/tagged/tfs) is a different (but confusingly similar) product.

I've merged and synonymized this tag with the [team-foundation-service](/questions/tagged/team-foundation-service) tag that [Will pointed out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163154/changing-tag-wiki-for-the-tfs-service-tag/163157#comment472342_163154).

Comment: Thanks, but I still have a concern about whether people who are thinking in terms of "tfs" will find a "team*" tag. We'll see.

Comment: Yeah, me too. It's yet [another unfortunate naming choice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138268/obsolete-synonym-microsoft-surface-and-pixelsense-are-now-separate-product).